# react-testing-library testing Ant Design modal

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I have a React component with Ant Design Modal inside it and I am trying to test that modal gets opened when a button it clicked:

The component:

```js
const ModalComponent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Modal title"
        centered
        visible={visible}
        onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
        onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
      >
        <p>some contents...</p>
        <p>some contents...</p>
        <p>some contents...</p>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

Test file:

```js
test('modal opening', async () => {
  const { queryByText } = render(<ModalComponent />);

  fireEvent.click(queryByText('Open Modal'));

  await waitFor(() => expect(queryByText('Modal title')).toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

The problem is that the modal DOM is never rendered in the test when I try to debug, so the test fails. It could be happening because the modal content is created outside of the component DOM tree right inside the body tag?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It works fine.

Comment: Also can't reproduce

Answer (score 12):

> There is no test failure that you have given from our side.

A little information from my side on `Antd modal` component.

Antd Modal during testing renders outside the `container`. This is because Antd uses the `rc-dialog` component and that component uses react portal to show modal which is always render outside the `root` div. In the same way, during testing modal will not render in the container but outside of it.

The test that you have given will `pass`(modal is present) because the `queryByText` will search the element in `document.body` not inside the container.

```
test('modal opening', async () => {
  const { baseElement, queryByText } = render(<ModalComponent />);

  fireEvent.click(queryByText('Open Modal'));

  expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot(); // added snapshot

  await waitFor(() => expect(queryByText('Modal title')).toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

`baseElement` will show all the elements that are present in the `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same use case, with a very similar component.

For some reason, if I triggered the event inside `act`, then the state of the component wouldn't be updated and the modal would never come up (even if a console.log in the event handler does show up in the console).

The solution was to do `userEvent.click` outside the `act`